# Print multiple regex matches using grep on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to match all digits including integer and decimal using grep, and print the matches on the same line (for easier use to plot using gnuplot). For instance,

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | grep -E -o '\d+(\.\d+)?'
```

prints

```
100
1000
3212.97
```

but how do I get all that in the same line like the following?

```
100  1000  3212.97
```

<sup>Editor's note: The original form of the question used just `\d+` as the regex, as reflected in some older answers.</sup>

Eventually, I would like it to work with multiple input files given like:

```
grep Throughput *.out | grep -E -o '\d+(\.\d+)?'
```

should print

```
100  1000  3212.97
200  3000  5444.77
300  5000  6769.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other variants:

Every example bellow uses this regex:

```
(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)
```

It matches, (in one group) the `ddd.` `ddd.ddd` `.ddd` `ddd`. If your decimals are different, for example don't want capture the `.ddd` (only decimal) variant, just remove it from the regex.

Usage for one file/string

```
#using `paste`
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97"  | grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' | paste -s -
# using echo for making the "one line"
echo $(grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' <<< "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97")
#HERESTRING and different separator
grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' <<< "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | paste -sd, -
#process substitution.. ;)
paste -sd ' ' <(grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' <<< "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97")
```

Same as above for multiple files, using `bash` loops. In the examples using `ff*` for the filenames.

```
#Using null-term find
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' "$file" | paste -s -
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ff\* -print0)

# or alternative - also prints filenames
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        echo "$file:" $(grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' $file)
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ff\* -print0)

echo Using FOR loop
for file in ff* ; do
        grep -Eo '(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)' "$file" | paste -s -
done
```

perl variants:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say "@{[/(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)/g]}"' ff*
```

also prints filenames

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say "$ARGV @{[/(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)/g]}"' ff*
```

also by using different field separator `\t`

```
perl -0777 -nE '$"="\t";say "$ARGV @{[/(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)/g]}"' ff*
```

All `perl` solution uses the [baby-cart operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret#Baby-cart). It is usually not recommented for a production code, but acceptable for the oneliners.

demo:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say "@{[/(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)/g]}"' <<< "some-111-decimal-222.-another-333.33-only-frac-.444.txt"
```

output

```
111 222. 333.33 .444
```

Comment: Regarding your perl answer, I'm pretty sure they only want `Throughput` lines.

Comment: @123 he said: _'m trying to match all digits_ ... so, **all** :)

Comment: Mine has decimal?

Comment: Also their example of multiple file is `grep Throughput *.out | grep -E '\d+(\.\d+)?'`, which would suggest they only want `Throughput` lines.

Comment: I don't understand what that means?

Comment: @jm666 I modified your answer to get the exact output I want `paste -sd ' '' ''\n' <(grep -Po '\d+(\.\d+)?' <<< \`grep Throughput *.out\`)` but some systems like the newer OS X version does not support `-P` flag in grep(because it isn't gnu grep).

Comment: @aruvaarumugam: A corrected version of your command that works on both macOS and Linux:
`paste -sd ' '' ''\n' <(grep -h Throughput *.out | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?')` but note that _it doesn't generalize_:
It only works if all matching lines contain exactly 3 numbers.

Comment: @mklement0 ? Don't understand. Why only 3 numbers?

Comment: @jm666: Because the 3 separator chars. passed to `paste -d` - space, space, newline - are applied _cyclically_ to the single stream of lines output by the `grep` commands.

Comment: @mklement0 ah soo - sure! :) I missed the `paste`'s args... sry for bugging you :)

Comment: @jm666 No worries at all - it's certainly not obvious how this command works.

Answer (score 2):

All of these solutions seem overtly complicated. The one presented is not particularly efficient but works:

```
while read -r line
do
echo $line | grep -o "PATTERN"  | tr "\n" " "  ; echo 
done < grep.txt
```

What it does:

1) Reads each line from file `grep.txt` separately and greps for the pattern. This allows you to have multiple patterns, you're not constrained by any particular number or very specific regex

2) Then you delete all unnecessary newlines with `tr`, convert them to spaces (for each specific line with any number of patterns, not for the whole file)

3) At the end the `echo` command  establishes to move to next line

What you end up is patterns from the same line in `grep.txt`on the same line, exactly as required.

Comment: This is infinitely better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single `gnu awk` command to get your output:

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" |
awk 'n = split($0, a, /[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/, vals) {
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i == n ? ORS : OFS)
}'

100 1000 3212.97
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution in Perl - this should get the floating points correctly too:

`perl -ne 'print join("\t", /(\d+(?:.\d+))/g); print "\n"' files*`

The first argument to `join` gives the field delimiter

The `?:` creates a so-called non-capturing-group to avoid duplicating the part after the floating point in the output - see: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings

Answer (score 1):

**Single-input case:**

```
$ echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | 
    grep -E -o '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' |
      paste -sd' ' -
100 1000 3212.97
```

- Note that I've changed the regex to be POSIX-compliant by replacing `\d` with `[0-9]`, given that you don't specify a platform.

  - BSD/macOS `grep` always understands `\d`, but GNU `grep` only does so with the `-P` option, which BSD/macOS doesn't support.
- `paste -sd ' ' -` replaces the newlines with spaces to get a single-line, space-separated list of numbers.

  - Operand `-` represents stdin, and is required in the BSD/macOS version of `paste` (optional with GNU `paste`).
  - `-s` concatenates the input lines in sequence.
  - `d' '` specifies that a space char. should be used as the separator (delimiter) *between* the input lines when concatenating; `paste`'s default is the tab char. (`\t`).
  - Using `paste` this way is superior to `tr '\n' ' '`, because the latter produces a trailing space.
    `paste` is also preferable to `column`, because the latter inserts line breaks if the output line grows wider than the display (and also *invariably* uses `\t` as the separator (the `-s` option only works with `-t`, which cannot be used here)).
    That said, `paste` cannot use a *multi-character* string as the fixed separator; the sample output in the question currently uses *2* spaces as the separator string, so if you wanted to achieve that, pipe `paste`'s output to `sed 's/ /  /g`

**Multi-file input case**:

<sup>The solution below uses a shell loop and 2 `grep` calls and a `paste` call per input file; consider using the more concise and efficient [Perl solution from inferno's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237142/45375) instead.</sup>

<sup>If you're willing to *assume that all matching lines contain exactly 3 numbers*, a more efficient solution with `grep` and `paste` is available (adapted from a solution attempt by the OP himself); `paste` is used to apply the 3 separator chars passed to `-d` (space, space, newline) *individually, cyclically*:

`paste -sd '  \n' <(grep -h Throughput *.out | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?')`</sup>

For *file-specific* output you must *process the files individually* (this assumes that all numbers *across matching lines* in a given file should be output as a *single* line):

```
for file in *.out; do
  grep Throughput "$file" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' | paste -sd ' ' -
done
```

- `for file in *.out` loops over all matching files individually.
- `grep Throughput "$file"` outputs all lines in the file at hand containing `Throughput`.
- `| grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'` then extracts the numbers from these lines, with each number printed on its own line.
- `| paste -sd ' ' -` then replaces the newlines with spaces to get a single-line list of numbers *per file*.

---

As for **why your approach won't work**:

```
grep Throughput *.out | grep -Eo '\d+(\.\d+)?'
```

sends a *single* stream of matching lines *across all input files* through the pipeline, so subsequent commands have no way of knowing which lines came from what file or line, making it impossible to group the numbers per input file or line (in a subsequent step) - unless you can make assumptions about the exact, fixed number of numbers contained in each input line.

Answer (score 1):

For your first simple case, you get the desired output with the following:

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | 
grep -o -E '[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' | column
```

Output:

```
100  1000  3212.97
```

EDIT:

Thanks to mklement0, who pointed out that using `paste` instead of `column` is probably a better solution:

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | 
grep -o -E '[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' | paste -s -
```

---

For multiple input files, I would also prefer a perl solution since it seems to be fairly easy and straightforward:

```
perl -nE 'say join "\t", /[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g' *.out
```

This example uses (just for the demonstration) three identical input files *file1.out*, *file2.out* and *file3.out*.

Output:

```
100  1000  3212.97
100  1000  3212.97
100  1000  3212.97
```

EDIT (in response to mklement0's comment):

To only process all lines containing the word "Throughput", here is a slightly extended example:

```
perl -nE 'say join "\t", /[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g if /Throughput/' *.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not sed? Simple ugly solution (feedback welcome):

```
$ echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | sed -re 's/[^0-9]+/ /g;s/ +/ /g;s/^ //' 
100 1000 3212 97
```

Or a explicitly match integers and floating points numbers:

```
$ echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | sed -re 's/([^0-9]+)([0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/\2 /g'
100 1000 3212.97
```

Comment: If the sed supports `-r` you can almost certainly use `;` instead of separate `-e`'s

Comment: thanks @123. Why is `;` better than several `-e` arguments?

Comment: I guess it's not technically , I just find it to be far more readable.

Comment: Use `-E`, not `-r`, for portability to other seds. `-r` is GNU only while `-E` works in GNU and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, Here is a simple command which would get the output you are trying to get.

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" | grep -oE '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' | tr '\n' ' ' |  paste -s

100 1000 3212.97
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you use `tr '\n' ' '` (which is not a good idea, because it adds a trailing space), `paste -s` has no effect at all. A single `paste` command should do.

Answer (score 0):

I really like anubhava `awk` script.

I wish to improve it with some more `gnu awk` feature to make it simpler and concise.

This trick will print all numbers in input line, no matter how many.

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" |
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"} {  # define input fields to be numbers
    $1 = $1; # recalculate the input line to hold only input fields
    print;   # print recalculated input line
}'
```

Or with one liner:

```
echo "bench-100-net-buffering1000.out:Throughput: 3212.97" |
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"}{$1=$1}1'
```