# Can grep print its matches to multiple lines, even if found on the same line?

Tags: grep

For example, with the following string:

```
[:variable_one] == options[:variable_two]
```

and the following grep argument:

```
grep -Eo "\[\:.*?\]"
```

It will show the output of:

```
[:variable_one] == options[:variable_two]
```

but instead, I'm looking to get an output of:

```
[:variable_one]
[:variable_two]
```

Is there a way to "split" each match into a separate line, even if it finds multiple matches on a single line? Basically looking for the opposite answer of this: [Print multiple regex matches using grep on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234244/print-multiple-regex-matches-using-grep-on-the-same-line)

Comment: i believe pure grep cannot do this. Use perl, python where you can control logic and output. The link you provided also didnt use just grep.

Comment: It's only finding (and printing) one match, because that match is 'greedy' -- it covers from the _first_ [ to the _last_ ]. Instead do `grep -o "\[:[^]]*\]"` (you don't need `-E` here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` and `]` (that is not part of a bracket expression) chars are not special inside a regex pattern. `*?` is treated as `*` in the POSIX ERE pattern, so it is too greedy and matches until the rightmost occurrence of `]`.

A POSIX BRE compliant regex for use with `grep` can look like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='[:variable_one] == options[:variable_two]'
grep -o "\[:[^][]*]" <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kFqPgu). Output:

```
[:variable_one]
[:variable_two]
```